# How should I use indexing in a very big table

Tags: mysql, indexing, scalability

Let's say I have the following table, which can contain 100M + rows.

Table example

```
id           user_id          week    content                    created
========================================================================
1            100022312        1     <data to be searched>    <timestamp>
2            102232123        1     <data to be searched>    <timestamp>
...
10.000.000   126387126        1     <data to be searched>    <timestamp>
10.000.001   100022312        2     <data to be searched>    <timestamp>
10.000.002   102232123        2     <data to be searched>    <timestamp>
...
20.000.000   126387126        2     <data to be searched>    <timestamp>
....
```

week 3, 4, 5, 6 .....

I will query the table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE week='2' AND content LIKE %word%
```

My question:

Could I use indexes to make this query run faster? How?

Is there a way to index a row? I mean, I would like to index each first row of each week, so that the next time I select, it first looks at the indexes, matches the week number, then it searches in that batch. This would mean `nr indexes == nr weeks`.

Data insertion does not matter. Also I don't need any sorting.

I am using MyISAM.

Comment: An index can't help with `LIKE '%word%'`.

Comment: But you can certainly add an index on `week`, and that will help.

Comment: Ok, suppose instead of `LIKE %word%` I have `cotent='word'`. 
Could you tell me how to add the index? Also, did you read my full question? Would I be able to add as many indexes as there are weeks (and on the first row of each week) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a multi-column index on the `week` and `content` columns:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD INDEX (week, content);
```

An index on a string column won't help if you're searching for text in the middle of it. But it will help with exact and prefix matches, will it will be useful if you do `content = 'word'` or `content LIKE 'word%'`.

Comment: Is there any way to see how many indexes will be created for my table?

Comment: One more thing (I'm new to indexes). If i have `SELECT * FROM table WHERE week=2 AND number1=10 AND number2=20`, do I create 3-column index? Would the number of `AND`s influence performance after being indexed?

Comment: Sounds like you need to read a good tutorial on how database indexes work. Start with [How MySQL Uses Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: I thought maybe you can sum it up so I don't need to read the docs :')
Again, thanks.

Comment: If you can index all the columns in an `AND`, it will find the appropriate rows entirely using the index, without having to compare any data from the table. There could be diminishing returns with too many indexes, though. Indexes take space.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to a `FULLTEXT` index on `content`.

Comment: All things considered, I think for my current project I'm better of without using any indexes.